# bootstrap jquery. How to get the nav name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the name of a bootstrap nav when I click it using jquery or javascript.  That is all, is a simple question.

Comment: The bootstrap nav has no name attribute. But you can get anything from a DOM element with jquery. Can you explain please what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by  `name` but try the following code :

```
$('.navbar-nav').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).text(); //To get the display text
    $(this).attr('name'); //if you mean attribute name
});
```

Hope this helps.